# IdentityServer with custom ClientStore

Tags: asp.net, authentication, identityserver4

I have the following. It works in the test environment:

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      // non-IdentityServer code here
      services.AddIdentityServer(
        options => {

        }
        )
          .AddApiAuthorization<UserEntity, LeagoDbContext>()
          .AddClientStore<MyClientStore>()
          ;
      services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
      // more non-IdentityServer code
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
       // non-IdentityServer code here
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseIdentityServer();
      // more non-IdentityServer code
    }
```

MyClientStore.cs:

```
public async Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId) {
  switch (clientId) {
    case "client":   // test store
      return await Task.FromResult(MyTestClient.TestClient);
    default:
      // this is the problem. Not sure what to do.
}
```

If I don't add MyClientStore in Startup.cs, the real environment works but the test one does not. So I somehow need to see what the real client looks like (so I can reconstruct it). Alternatively, I might inject the default client store into my custom one and call it in the default case of the switch statement above. But I'm not sure how to do either one. Note that the default store in turn has dependencies on ILogger and IConfigurationDbContext.

Comment: It can be anything you like that returns a unique `Client` instance per clientId. You can map it to a database table, configuration file, etc. Personally I usually use the [EF package](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/reference/ef.html) that does this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could return null if no user found or any user according to your custom condition

```cs
public async Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId) {
  switch (clientId) {
    case "client":   // test store
      return await Task.FromResult(MyTestClient.TestClient);
    default:
       // you could return null here instead if no user
       return await Task.FromResult(MyTestClient.AnotherClient);
}
```